# How do I get powershell to return all users with MFA turned off?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm rather new to powershell scripting and seem to be having issues getting powershell to return a list of all users within a particular group that have MFA turned off. I plan on having the output put into a .csv file later. This is what I've cobbled together sofar:

```
Connect-MsolService


$GroupA = <Group ID>
$Path = <File Path>

Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $GroupA | Get-MsolUser | ? 
{$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods -ne $null} | Sort DisplayName
```

However some of the users in the list it returns have MFA turned on. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: your title says you want MFA turned on. your last sentence says "some have MFA turned out" and implies that you want something else. _what do you actually want_?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "turned off". I want it to print a list of users from a group with MFA turned off.

Comment: please, modify your Question to show what you want & what result you actually got. [*grin*]

Comment: there is a known glitch in powershell that makes it somewhat iffy to put `$Null` on the _right_ side of a comparison. that is why the recommended pattern is to use `$Null -ne $Thing` instead of `$Thing -ne $Null`. ///// try it that way ... you _may_ get different results. [*grin*]

Comment: Or use `{$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -eq 0}`

Comment: Thank you @Theo, your suggestion was perfect. I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Glad to have helped a bit!

Answer (score 0):

That attribute will never equal `$null` from what I can tell, even when it's empty. Eg. if you run:

```
Get-MsolUser | ForEach-Object { $_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.GetType() }
```

you'll see output like

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object
```

no matter whether the attribute has values in it or not, there's always a list object there.

I'd go with @Theo's suggestion, so something like this:

```
Connect-MsolService
$GroupA = <Group ID>
$Path = <File Path>
Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $GroupA | Get-MsolUser | 
    Where-Object { $_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -eq 0 } |
        Sort-Object DisplayName
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I ended up doing. Thank you.